# Mysql optimizer chooses wrong table order in query

Tags: mysql, join

We have simple database with 4 tables: files, file_versions, users, organizations.
I do select all files which owned by some organization with some condition on trashing date by this query:

```
select * FROM organizations o
    LEFT JOIN users u ON o.id=u.organization_id
    LEFT JOIN files f ON u.user_identity=f.owner_identity
    LEFT JOIN file_versions fv ON f.owner_identity=fv.owner_identity
        AND f.local_path=fv.local_path
    WHERE o.id=2001237 AND o.trashed_file_age_limit>=1
        AND f.trashing_date<(1433943058 - o.trashed_file_age_limit*24*60*60);
```

`Explain select` shows me that optimizer choose wrong table order, which is different from query order(organizations-> users->files->file_versions):

```
mysql> explain select * FROM organizations o     LEFT JOIN users u ON o.id=u.organization_id     LEFT JOIN files f ON u.user_identity=f.owner_identity     LEFT JOIN file_versions fv ON f.owner_identity=fv.owner_identity         AND f.local_path=fv.local_path     WHERE o.id=2001237 AND o.trashed_file_age_limit>=1         AND f.trashing_date<(1433943058 - o.trashed_file_age_limit*24*60*60);
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                    | key      | key_len | ref                                                | rows      | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | const  | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY  | 4       | const                                              |         1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ALL    | PRIMARY                          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                                               | 109615125 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,identity,organization_id | identity | 36      | filemirror.f.owner_identity                        |         1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fv    | ref    | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY  | 3035    | filemirror.u.user_identity,filemirror.f.local_path |         1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Of couse this query is slow because of full scan by files table and I have to use STRAIGHT_JOIN(which is not equivalent to LEFT JOIN) to fix table order and make query faster.

```
mysql> explain select * FROM organizations o     STRAIGHT_JOIN users u ON o.id=u.organization_id     STRAIGHT_JOIN files f ON u.user_identity=f.owner_identity     STRAIGHT_JOIN file_versions fv ON f.owner_identity=fv.owner_identity         AND f.local_path=fv.local_path     WHERE o.id=2001237 AND o.trashed_file_age_limit>=1         AND f.trashing_date<(1433943058 - o.trashed_file_age_limit*24*60*60);
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                    | key     | key_len | ref                                                | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | const | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY | 4       | const                                              |       1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref   | PRIMARY,identity,organization_id | PRIMARY | 4       | const                                              |      36 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref   | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY | 36      | filemirror.u.user_identity                         | 6089324 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fv    | ref   | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY | 3035    | filemirror.u.user_identity,filemirror.f.local_path |       1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is why mysql can change table order in not symmetric join operation?

Tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `file_versions` (
  `owner_identity` char(36) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `local_path` varchar(999) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `version_number` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`owner_identity`,`local_path`,`version_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `owner_identity` char(36) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `local_path` varchar(999) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `version_number` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
..
  `trashing_date` int(11) default NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`owner_identity`,`local_path`),
  KEY `trashing_date` (`trashing_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
  `trashed_file_age_limit` int(11) default NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_identity` char(36) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin NOT NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`organization_id`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `identity` (`user_identity`),
  KEY `organization_id` (`organization_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Mysql version 5.5

Comment: Note that `LEFT  JOIN f WHERE f` is the same as `INNER JOIN f ON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the rows estimates, mysql thinks that it will need to read 109M rows of files table in first plan and 6M for each of 36 users = 216M rows for second plan. So it seems reasonable to read all 109M rows only once and in priamry key order instead reading them in separate blocks.. Those estimates does not seem very reasonable to me, so I would try running analyze table on files, but they are estimates so maybe you wont get better numbers.

Using LEFT join and then adding condition on the table to WHERE turns it into INNER join as Strawberry says in their comment - you have to have value for the where condition to ever be true, so mysql feels free to reorder those a bit, maybe even it seems better for optimizer to do "really-inner" joins first, so that may be second reason for that plan.

You can try using STRAIGHT_JOIN in different way - if you put it just once right after SELECT, then your join order is used by optimizer if possible (it usually is barring some weird right joins and other corner cases) without changing join type on specific tables (it is then used as sort of FLAG, in the way SQL_NO_CACHE is used to signalize something, instead of as special join type)

Then to make it even better, you may try adding index to files on (owner_identity, trashing_date) which should help in localizing specific files for each user and not globally as with current key on (trashing_date) only.